# How to completely protect Google Drive app on Android?

Tags: samsung, google-drive

I am using Secure Folder on my Samsung for some of my apps, and I installed Google Drive too. But I am also logged in to my Google account outside of the Secure Folder - for backups and the Photos app - I don't need to have my photos in Secure Folder.

But what's the point of having this if anyone who has access to my phone can simply install Google Drive and will automatically be logged in? How to prevent it, I mean after installing the app it would ask for credentials.

Comment: Google uses single-sign-on system, so once the Google account is on your phone all Google apps have access to it and thus to the data of the account. The only workaround is to work with multiple Google accounts.

Comment: Robert is correct.  The other alternative is to use a software/service provider (one besides Google) that implements a more useful security model.

Comment: Sure, I get it. But is there some other workaround because I want to use google with single account? Is prohibiting installing drive application possible?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. I guess an alternative solution is to install an "app locker" app to password-protect the Google Drive app.